# Does the Base of a topology form itself a topology?

Tags: general-topology

I am studying topology,and in the beginning I came to know about bases of a topology and I feel problem there. By topology  in a special class of subsets of a set X such that they satisfy some specific properties. A base is a 
sub-collection of the topology such that any open set i.e any set from the topology can be written as a union of elements of the base.
Now my question is can the base itself be a topology?
The question arises to me in solving the following problem.
Let $\mathbf{R}$ be the set of reals and $B=\{[a,b):b>a\}$.

1. Is $B$ a topology?
2. Is $B$ a base of a topology?

Now we know that $B$ is a base for the lower limit topology on $\mathbf R$.
While solving this I thought that $\emptyset $ doesn't belong to $B$, so it is not a topology, but then I thought that the $\emptyset $ is always a subset of any set so $B$ must be a topology.

Again while proving B to be a base  for the lower limit topology,taking any open set $G$ and and taking any point $x \in G$ we see that $x$ belongs to $[x,x+1)$ which belongs​ to $B$, hence it is a base.
Am I wrong​ in thinking?. If so hope to get corrected.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with some topology $\tau$ then you can discern a base for $\tau$ as done in the answer of Caligula.

But if you start without a topology then also some reasonable things can be said about bases.

---

Let $X$ be a set and let $\mathcal B\subseteq\wp(X)$. Then $\mathcal B$ is a base for a topology iff:

- The intersection of two elements of $\mathcal B$ can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal B$.
- For every $x\in X$ there is a $B\in\mathcal B$ with $x\in B$.

Now observe that a topology will satisfy both conditions, so it is formally correct to say that a topology is also a base for a topology.

You can wonder: if $\mathcal B$ is indeed a base for a topology, then is this topology unique? And how does it look like? Yes, it is unique and can be described as the collection of all subsets of $X$ that can be written as union of elements of $\mathcal B$.

Denoting this collection by $\mathcal B^{\bigcup}$  it can be shown that: $$\mathcal B\text{ is a base for a topology }\iff\mathcal B^{\bigcup}\text{ is a topology}$$

Note that for a base $\mathcal B$ we have: $$\mathcal B^{\bigcup}=\mathcal B\iff\mathcal B\text{ is a topology}$$ This because a topology is closed under unions.

Comment: Oh! That's nice. That means if a set X with a  topology is given and B is a base for the topology,then B may not be closed under unions ?

Comment: Indeed. In e.g. the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ the intervals form a base, but $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ is not an interval.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, recall the definition of base.

**Definition.** Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. A family $\mathscr{B}\subseteq \tau$ of open sets is called a *base* for $\tau$ if (1) $\mathscr{B}$ is an open cover of $X$ and (2) for any $U,V\in \mathscr{B}$ and for any $x\in U\cap V$ there exists $W\in \mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in W\subseteq U\cap V$.

I think you can easily see that your example is a base with respect to this definition. But it can not be a topology on $\mathbb{R}$, the real line.

The reason is the following. If $\mathscr{B}=\{[a,b):a<b\}$ were a topology, it would be closed under infinite unions. But what about that?
$$ \bigcup_{n>0} [1/n,2)$$

Comment: I got it.Thanks for your answer.That means $\emptyset$ doesn't belong to the set is not an appropriate reason for not being a topology?. One more thing,In general can a base of a topology form itself a topology? I know that the topology itself a base but what about the converse?